# Is this Western-style novelization of Obi-Wan's exodus canon?

Tags: star-wars, novel, tv

A friend of mine had the idea for a Western-style TV show or movie series chronicling Obi-Wan's years on Tatooine before his adventures with Luke. I found an interview about a novel called "Star Wars: Kenobi" here: https://www.comicbookmovie.com/scifi_movies/star_trek/what-happened-to-obi-wan-between-revenge-of-the-sith-a-new-a86980

Is this canon? And is there any hope for a cinematic adventure devoted solely to Ben?

Comment: No. Like all EU novels written before Disney took over LucasFilm, this novel is part of the "Legends" canon. As such, the events may (or may not) have happened.

Comment: For the record, Uncle Ben is the dude who makes rice (or possibly Spider-Man's dead guardian). I think you mean Old Ben.

Comment: in regards to the last question - stay tuned to Rebels Season 3 which just started (no spoilers here fwiw - just a guess based on the most recent episode). There are also new canon comics which cover some pre ANH Kenobi things

Comment: @Valorum We don't really know.  Perhaps Uncle Ben was a well-known entity on Tatooine.  You know, before his adventures with "Like".  :P